# Is there a way to programmatically zoom in or pan a Bing map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

After an exhaustive search, I decided to ask here: I would like to initialize a Bing map from a distance and then zoom in to about level 8. I was thinking after a set time to then zoom out a ways and then pan to a new location and then zoom in again.

Is this possible using the javascript API? I've only seen examples of doing this in WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: Maybe implement this using settimeout?  http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 1):

If understand your question, you need to create map passing the container of the map.
In that way the map is created with options set to null.

```
var oMap = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(divMapContainer, null)
```

After the map is displayed you call setView method, and passing optional parameters as object.

The optional parameters are center and zoom.

```
setTimeout(function () {
     oMap.setView({
          center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0),
          zoom: 8
     });
}, 1000);
```

The function executed after one second in order to give a map some time to finish loading.